# Secure Broadcast Channel

Tags: transport-security

I've read a paper that says that one of the "assumptions" that it makes is secure broadcast. Why is this an assumption? Can't a broadcast channel be built with simple primitives--i.e. encrypt and sign messages with a shared key?

And, assuming that there is something more that I'm missing, how are broadcast channels usually approximated in practice?

Comment: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/15-749/READINGS/required/resilience/lamport82.pdf $\;$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not broadcast, but *secure* broadcast. Secure broadcast guarantees that every recipient ends up with the same message.

If you just sign the message and send it separately to each recipient, a malicious sender could send different messages to different recipients.

A simple solution is that each recipient counter-signs the message and re-sends it to the other recipients. Once everyone has everyone's signature on the message, they accept.

There are better solutions, but all of them have an associated cost.